# Counting frequency of a sequence within a vector

Tags: matlab, sequence, counting

Let's say I have a binary vector of length N, and I'm looking for the frequency of each of the following 16 sequences in that vector:

```
0000, 0001, 0010, 0011, ..., 1111
```

What is the easiest way to count these frequency of each of these sequences in the vector?  Ideally, I'd like to know how to do this in MatLab.

Comment: In what form do you have the binary vector? Are these strings? Is this a cell array?

Comment: The binary vector is in `vector` form in MatLab, so it looks like `[0 0 1 1 0 1 0 ...]`.

Comment: Do you care about the window size into the data? For example, suppose that `vector = [0 0 0 0 1]`. In your problem, does this vector "contain" 1 occurrence of "0000" and one occurrence of "0001", even though they overlap... or would you say it only contains the first one?

Comment: @EMS that vector contains both.  Each sequence has length 4, and sequences can overlap.  So the vector have length N has N-3 sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the numbers 0x0 to 0xF, just ++ them as indexes into an array of size 0xF.  Sum array elements, and A[i]/N is your frequency.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to solve this is to convert the binary numbers to decimal numbers, and then use either `hist` or `accumarray` to count occurences. I start out with reshaping the array into an (N-3)-by-4 array, which allows vectorizing all calculations.

```
%# make up some test data
data = [0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1];

%# reshape into a (N-3)-by-4 array
%# idx is [1 2 3 4;2 3 4 5;...]
idx = bsxfun(@plus,(1:length(data)-3)',0:3); %'# 
data = data(idx);

%# convert binary numbers to decimals
%# use matrix multiplication
decData = data * [8;4;2;1];

%# count number of occurences - possible values are 0 through 15
counts = hist(decData,0:15);
```

`counts(1)` counts the number of times the sequence `0 0 0 0` has appeared in the list.

Comment: This doesn't account for possible overlap of the sequences, which the OP indicates is necessary for this problem in the comments.

Comment: @EMS: yep, that requirement was added after I posted

Comment: @jamaicaworm: I have updated my solution so that overlapping sequences are taken into account.

Comment: +1 for the use of `bsxfun` and `hist`. Although I think it's possible to have a value of zero (sequence of `0000`), so you need `hist(decData, 0:15)`. As written, `counts(1)` counts the number of times the sequence `0001` has appeared. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

```
count = zeros(1,16);
vector = [1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0];
N = length(vector);

for ii = 1:(N-3)
    cur_seq = vector(ii:ii+3);        % Grab the running set of four entries
    cur_num = cur_seq*[8; 4; 2; 1];   % Convert these entries to non-binary.

    % Update the count of the sequence that has cur_num
    % as its non-binary integer representation. Note that
    % you must use cur_num+1 as the index since Matlab is
    % 1-based, but the integers from your sequences are 0
    % through 15.

    count(cur_num+1) = count(cur_num+1) + 1;
end
```

Now `count(1)` counts occurrences of `[0,0,0,0]`, and `count(2)` counts occurrences of `[0,0,0,1]` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Let the data and block length be defined as

```
x = [ 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1];
M = 4;
```

Then the result can be obtained with a single line as follows:

```
result = histc(conv(x, 2.^(0:M-1), 'valid'), 0:2^M-1);
```

In this example,

```
result =
     2   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

meaning there were `2` ocurrences of `[0 0 0 0]`, `1` occurrence of `[0 0 0 1]` etc.

**How this works**:

1. Compute a convolution (using [`conv`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html)) with powers of `2`, to find the decimal representation of each sliding length-`M` binary number.
2. Count occurrences of each number obtained in step 1 (using [`histc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html)).

Answer (score 0):

If `a` is holding your data:

```
c = []
for el = a,
  c = [c, sum(a==el)];
end
```

This is quadratic, but will have the counts at the same indices as `a`. It would work also if you don't know the range in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what this does, but it does not answer this question.

Comment: If a is holding values, c will have for each of the values the number overall occurrences. But maybe I have misinterpreted the question.